# Is it possible to wrap this requierements in one query?

Tags: sql

Here is the setup:

- MasterTable has a booleand HasDetails field and an integer Score field.
- If this field is true then the DetailsTable holds one or more records with a field MasterTableID that holds value of the corresponding MasterTable.AutoID.
- Each child record in the Details table holds an integer Frequency value and a Score Field.

We want to know the count of the MasterTable.Score field grouped by its integer value, augmented with the number of times the same value is found in de DetailsTable.Score field multiplied by its Frequency and divided by the sum of the Frequencies it shares with the records that have the same DetailsTable.MasterTableID

A typical result would be:

### MasterTable

```
AutoID Score HasDetails
1       100   False
2       ?     True
3       200   False
4       300   False
```

### DetailsTable

```
MasterTableID Score Frequency
2              200      1
2              300      1
```

Result of the query must be:

```
100   1
200   1.5
300   1.5
```

Comment: Is that second row in `DetailsTable` supposed to have an id of `3` as shown, or should it be `2`?  If the `3` is correct, then I don't understand how you arrive at the desired results.

Comment: Is `HasDetails` really significant, or is it just a proxy for whether relevant rows exist in `DetailsTable`?  Is it possible that there would be rows in `DetailsTable` which should be ignored, because the corresponding `HasDetails` value is `False`?

Comment: I can't derived the same results as you do, are you sure that your description to your calculation and the example data are correct?

Comment: @DaveCosta: Sorry, the second MasterTableID shoud be 2. I thought that I had repaired that on posting, but it seems to have been reverted.

Comment: @DaveCosta: All records in the DetailsTable are significant. So the HasDetails field can be ignored (at a performance cost as typically only 1% of the MasterTable records will have child entries in the DetailsTable)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this syntax will be OK for your RDBMS but give it a try.

```
SELECT master_count.Score, score_count + COALESCE( weighted_frequency, 0 )
  FROM
  (SELECT Score, COUNT(*) score_count FROM MasterTable GROUP BY Score) master_count
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT Score, SUM(Frequency/sum_frequency) weighted_frequency
     FROM DetailsTable JOIN
         (SELECT MasterTableID, SUM(Frequency) sum_frequency
            FROM DetailsTable GROUP BY MasterTableID) DetailsSum
         ON DetailsTable.MasterTableId = DetailsSum.MasterTableID
     GROUP BY Score) detail_count
  ON detail_count.Score = master_count.Score
  )
```

This assumes that, if there are values of `Score` in the detail table that don't exist in the master table at all, you want to ignore them.  If that's not the case, you could modify it like so:

```
SELECT COALESCE( master_count.Score, detail_count.Score ), score_count + COALESCE( weighted_frequency, 0 )
  FROM
  (SELECT Score, COUNT(*) score_count FROM MasterTable GROUP BY Score) master_count
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT Score, SUM(Frequency/sum_frequency) weighted_frequency
     FROM DetailsTable JOIN
         (SELECT MasterTableID, SUM(Frequency) sum_frequency
            FROM DetailsTable GROUP BY MasterTableID) DetailsSum
         ON DetailsTable.MasterTableId = DetailsSum.MasterTableID
     GROUP BY Score) detail_count
  ON detail_count.Score = master_count.Score
  )
```

Comment: I have some trouble checking it: the Jet engine does not support Coalesce and SQL-CE does not support Full Outer Joins. I will test it later!